# Аболютно позиционированный элемент расшряет страницу

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, позиционирование

На странице есть элемент, который по определенному условию скрывается: ему задается transform: translateX() и position: absolute. Но сам элемент может оказаться выше получившейся страницы без него. Поэтому он уходит вниз за body, и добавляется прокрутка не до конца body, а до конца этого элемента. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы такой элемент не влиял на прокрутку? Возможно ли вообще ограничить всю прокрутку на странице тегом body?

Вот код:

```
.block {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition-duration: .8s;
    transition-property: transform, opacity;
}

.block.opened {
    position: relative;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: none;
}

.block.closing {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Закрытым элементом считается элемент без класса, открытым - с классом opened, закрывающимся - с классами opened и closing. То есть для закрытия добавляется класс closing, после окончания анимации он вместе с классом opened убираются. Для открытия просто добавляется класс opened.

Comment: Добавьте к родительскому элементу overflow: hidden

Comment: можно попробовать даже к body или добавить div блок-обертку с width: 100%; overflow: hidden, как сказал @Vearo

Answer (score 0):

Там не только вертикальный, но и горизонтальный скролл появляется. Поэтому вместо этого можно скрывать через `width: 0; overflow: hidden;`

```js
var bubu = document.getElementById('bubu');
var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');

bubu.addEventListener('click', function(){
  toggle.classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  height: 3000px;
  width: 30vw;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}
.hidden {
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="toggle" class="toggle">Какой-то текст</div>

<button id="bubu">Toggle</button>
```

Или, если translateX крайне важен для красивой анимации, можно примерно так:

```
/*псевдокод*/

кнопка.addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  блок.classList.add('скрыть'); // скажем, скроется в течение секунды
  setTimeout(function(){
    блок.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.style.overflow = '';
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Текст при скрытии прыгает. ести там картинка с фикс размером, то ок, иначе ваш вариант не оч

Comment: @Za Ars решается добавлением дополнительного блока внутри основного. И у внутреннего - `min-width: **;`

Answer (score 0):

Решил добавлением height: 0 и overflow: hidden для элемента без класса. А у body и так overflow-x: hidden.